# J-meter-How can I extract a Code in response header from url coming in Location

Tags: jmeter, header

I need to get the Code of request gone to location: https://example.com/login?code=hdfjhsjfhsjfhshfsfshkfhshfM&put=put(I am getting from response header of each request)

I need to extract "hdfjhsjfhsjfhshfsfshkfhshfM" value form above

I tried with regular expression extractor and extracted the value.
its extract all value like   login?code=hdfjhsjfhsjfhshfsfshkfhshfM&put=put but i need only code

Please check the response header below: Check for location: https://example.com/login?code=hdfjhsjfhsjfhshfsfshkfhshfM&put=put

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

> ```
> Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 17:13:29 GMT
> Server: Apache
> Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Expires: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 17:13:29 GMT
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
> Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=fd; expires=Thu, 24-Jan-2019 19:13:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure
> Set-Cookie: laravelsession=df; expires=Thu, 24-Jan-2019 19:13:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
> location: https://example.com/login?code=hdfjhsjfhsjfhshfsfshkfhshfM&put=put
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Set-Cookie: abcLB-Staging=df; path=/; Httponly; Secure
> Content-Length: 2193
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is adding a [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) as a child of the request and configuring it like:

[image]

Once done you should be able to access the extracted value as `${code}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

In general it might be the case you don't even need to extract the code, if you allow JMeter to [redirect automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) (or follow redirects) it will follow the URL from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) header in a sub-request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri it is working and now I can extract the exact code vale which I want thanks a lot for you support